# automatic clicks on links and doing something with every page's DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some links in a web page ,what i want to do :

- Trigger click event on every link
- When the page of every link is loaded , do something with page's DOM(fillProducts here)

What i have tried :

```
function start(){

    $('.category a').each(function(i){

         $.when($(this).trigger('click')).done(function() {

              fillProducts() ;
        });
     })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not very close at all, it's the complete wrong use of functions that works with promises and deferred objects, which is not what `trigger()` returns at all. Anchors don't really have load events either, and I'm guessing you're loading all these pages with ajax, otherwise what you're doing makes no sense at all, and then you'll probably have to hook into the ajax calls that these links trigger, and it's going to be a lot more complicated than you seem to think.

Comment: sorry, i haven't understood very well , but what you said is true , those links are ajax calls , they filtre the page , and i want to play with the new pages every time a link is click(div of page changed)

Comment: Then hook into the ajax function that loads the pages, not the click on the anchor.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do that (PS:i'm not the owner of website , i'm playing with console of browser)

Comment: Are you using a browser extension here or are you adding a script to the actual website

Comment: @megawac ,sincerely i use only the console in browser , no extensions , i copy past script in console

Comment: Can you confirm how the actual ajax call is being made i.e. through jQuery or a manually created xhr

Comment: @megawac i don't think it matters however i can't see js code

Comment: It does matter. Inspect the code with console and see how they'remaking the requests because what you're asking for would be a major security breach that browsers would never allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that may work for you if they are sending their ajax requests using jQuery. If they aren't you're going to need to get devilishly hacky to accomplish what you're asking (eg [overriding the `XMLHttpRequest` object and creating a global observer queue for ajax requests](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page#answer-5202999)). As you haven't specified how they're sending the ajax request I hope this approach works for you.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    complete: function(jQXHR) {
        if(interested)
        //do your work
    }
});
```

The code below will click a link, wait for the ajax request to be sent and be completed, run you `fillProducts` function and then click the next link. Adapting it to run all the clicks wouldn't be difficult

```
function start(){
    var links = $('.category a');
    var i = 0;
    var done = function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            complete: $.noop//remove your handler
        });
    }
    var clickNext = function() {
        $(links.get(i++)).click();//click current link then increment i
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        complete: function(jQXHR) {
            if(i < links.length) {
                fillProducts();
                clickNext();
            } else {
                done();
            }
        }
    });
    clickNext();
}
```

If this doesn't work for you try hooking into the [other jqXHR events](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) before hacking up the site too much.

**Edit** here's a more reliable method in case they override the `complete` setting

```
(function() {
    var $ajax = $.ajax;
    var $observer = $({});

    //observer pattern from addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjquery
    var obs = window.ajaxObserver = {
        subscribe: function() {
            $observer.on.apply($observer, arguments);
        },
        unsubscribe: function() {
            $observer.off.apply($observer, arguments);
        },
        once: function() {
            $observer.one.apply($observer, arguments);
        },
        publish: function() {
            $observer.trigger.apply($observer, arguments);
        }
    };

    $.ajax = function() {
        var $promise = $ajax.apply(null, arguments);
        obs.publish("start", $promise);
        return $promise;
    };
})();
```

Now you can hook into $.ajax calls via

```
ajaxObserver.on("start", function($xhr) {//whenever a $.ajax call is started
    $xhr.done(function(data) {
        //do stuff
    })
});
```

So you can adapt the other snippet like

```
function start(){
    var links = $('.category a');
    var i = 0;

    var clickNextLink = function() {
        ajaxObserver.one("start", function($xhr) {
            $xhr.done(function(data) {
                if(i < links.length) {
                    fillProducts();
                    clickNextLink();
                } else {
                    done();
                }

            });
        })
        $(links.get(i++)).click();//click current link then increment i
    }
    clickNextLink();
}
```

Comment: Thank you man ,page used $.ajax indeed .Your function needed to be recursive and passing i parameter to it starting by i=0 , thanks ,it works,i can't award you the bounty until i 22hours pass

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is much more complicated than you seem to be giving it credit for. If you could scrape webpages, including AJAX content, in 7 lines of js in the console of a web browser you'd put Google out of business.

I'm guessing at what you want a bit, but I think you want to look at using a headless browser, e.g. [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). You'll then be able to scrape the target pages and write the results to a JSON file (other formats exist) and use that to `fillProducts` - whatever that does.

Also, are you stealing data from someone else's website? Cause that isn't cool.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this answer , i looked at http://phantomjs.org/network-monitoring.html and i think that your answer is really helpful,i will wait until i get all responses and if your answer still the best , i award you the bounty.Thanks again for PhantomJS keyword

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function start(){

        $('.category a').each(function(i){

              $(this).click(); 
              fillProducts() ;

         })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I get ya now.   This is like say:

when facebook loads,   I want to remove the adverts by targeting specific class, and then alter the view that i actually see.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Is a plugin for firefox, this will allow you to create a javascript file, will then allow you to target a specific element or elements within the html rendered content.

IN order to catch the ajax request traffic, you just need to catcher that within your console.

I can not give you a tutorial on greasemonkey, but you can get the greasemonkey script for facebook, and use that as a guide.

http://mashable.com/2008/12/25/facebook-greasemonkey-scripts/

hope this is it